# Haproxy ssl redirect handshake failure

Tags: redirect, ssl, haproxy

I have haproxy v1.5.4 working with http & https. I am binding *:80 & :*443 to the same frontend and using the same acls.

I want to create an http -> https redirect

```
frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/pki/tls/certs/...

    ...

    acl is_office path_beg /office
    http-request redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc } is_office

    use_backend office if is_office
```

This causes

```
10.XXXXX:36909 [16/Dec/2015:17:23:07.678] http-in/2: SSL handshake failure
```

when I access over http (expecting the redirect)

If I access via https then it correctly hits the backend and proxies through to the service over 443.

```
backend office
  balance roundrobin
  server backbone-daily 10.XXXXXX:443 ssl check verify none
```

The self-signed cert validates and works without the redirect. It feels like i'm missing something in the redirect stage.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: First guess is that you have "verify" set for the backend, but are using a self-signed certificate which would fail verification.

Comment: Also, do you purposely have an SSL certificate both on the load balancer *and* the backend server?  (2 separate certificates)

Comment: Hi, the backend has **verify none** as its a self signed cert. I want to proxy traffic through to apache over SSL. I can terminate SSL for some services but I don't want to for CAS. I assumed that because I can hit the backend successfully when using https the redirect should just work

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: Hi sorry this was at a previous company - Now I terminate SSL at the load balancer ALB etc and dont ever bother at this layer

Comment: Did anyone get a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Since we use the HAProxy Plugin with OPNsense, which only has a GUI, I can't give an answer containing working code. However, I can retrace the steps that finally made this work for us.

1. Set up your mapping rules as usual
2. Set up a rule HTTP_REDIRECT without any conditions but with the function `http-request redirect scheme https`
3. Create *two* public services, one for port 443 and one for port 80
4. Set up the public service for 443 with SSL Offloading and your mapping rules
5. Set up the public service for 80 *without* SSL Offloading, and only your HTTP_REDIRECT rule

I suspect this would translate to code something like this:

```
frontend http-in
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/pki/tls/certs/...
    use_backend office if is_office

frontend no-ssl-http-in
    bind *:80
    http-request redirect scheme https
```

Hope this helps anyone who is still looking for a solution.

Comment: In the HAProxy service management, there's a section called "Config Export" which shows you the haproxy.cfg file that is generated from the GUI.  You could look there to see if the code is what you expect.